# wsadmin application install leaves out Security role to user/group mapping

Tags: scripting, jython, websphere-7, wsadmin

I am facing an issue while installing my application's .ear file from the `wsadmin` command line, using the below command (see below) -- which I copied as is from the Websphere's "View administrative scripting command for last action" , after I tried to do this manually from the console. The issue is after deployment completes and I go to the application , I don't see the "Security role to user/group mapping" link under Detailed Properties , but I do see this when I install the app from the console whilst I accept all default values using the Fast Path approach .
PS : I am using Websphere 7.0.0.23 on a Windows 2008 R2 64 bit machine. Also, if I leave out all the options in the `AdminApp.install()` command and just use `AdminApp.install('C:\pathToMyEar')` I see the Security mapping link , but then I need to at the least pass the application's name , without which the name ends up being some random string.

> AdminApp.install('C:/fakepath/myApplication.ear', '[ -nopreCompileJSPs
>   -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -nodeployejb -appname myApplicationRestEAR -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled
>   -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*.dll=755#.*.so=755#.*.a=755#.*.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -MapModulesToServers [[ myApplicationRest myApplicationRest.war,WEB-INF/web.xml
>   WebSphere:cell=TestNode01Cell,node=TestNode01,server=server1 ]]
>   -MapRolesToUsers [[ security AppDeploymentOption.No AppDeploymentOption.Yes "" "" AppDeploymentOption.No "" "" ]]]' )

Many thanks ,
Chethan

Comment: There are only 5 parameters of `MapRolesToUsers` in documentation and also in armstrhb answer (see below). Why do You have `MapRolesToUsers` with 8 parameters? What these parameters do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are some extra arguments at the end of the -MapRolesToUsers block.  I'm not sure if those are throwing off wsadmin.  Here's the IBM documentation on MapRolesToUsers ([source](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html)):

```
AdminApp.install('myapp.ear', '[-MapRolesToUsers [["All Role" No Yes "" ""]["Every Role" Yes No "" ""] [DenyAllRole No No user1 group1]]]')

where {{"All Role" No Yes "" ""} corresponds to the following:

"All Role"  Represents the role name
No          Indicates to allow access to everyone (yes/no)
Yes         Indicates to allow access to all authenticated users (yes/no)
""          Indicates the mapped users
""          Indicates the mapped groups
```

Try changing the MapRolesToUsers block to this:

```
 -MapRolesToUsers [[ security AppDeploymentOption.No AppDeploymentOption.Yes "" "" ]]
```

Comment: Thank you , I tried this too with same results , however , there is a catch : a restart of WAS rectified this and I could see the link "Security role user/group mapping" right-away after the restart and regardless of whether I used my way or yours for the syntax.

Comment: make sure you don't forget to 
`$AdminConfig save`
also might get timeout if so check: `C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\MyAppSrv123\properties\soap.client.props`

here my example for groups
`$AdminApp view myAPP123 {-MapRolesToUsers}`
`$AdminApp edit myAPP123 {-MapRolesToUsers { {"MyAdmins" No no "" "AdminG|WAS AdminG"}} }`

Comment: In my case the syntax is `AdminApp.edit('MY_WAR', ['-MapRolesToUsers', [['Administrators','No','Yes','wsadmin','']] ])` and `AdminConfig.save()`